# Retrieve the old file name from git

Tags: git

I used the command git log -- follow   , and the command return all the commit history related to this file. however, when I use checkout command the checkout the file on a spacific commit it give an error like:

`error: pathspec <mypath/file> did not match any file(S) known to git` .

my question: is there is git command that show all  the commit that touch a specific file and show the file name and path at that commit, since the file or path could change.

[edited]

I have a file I need to know all old name and path in at specific commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `git log -M --summary..`

Comment: Than you for your answer: Now how should I add the file path to this command

Comment: By `git log -M --summary`, Information of all file create/rename will be output. you can follow those information to find what you need.

Comment: I need to see only the old file name for spacific file

Comment: Because git save changes basically on source tree snapshot mode, I do not think there is one command to get the timeline of renamed file automatically. you must retrieve the timeline through tracing the renaming log by yourself.